debounce vs useDeferredValue
I faced a problem of choice between my useDebouncedValue hook and react's useDerredValue in my particular case.
First let me introduce how my useDebouncedValue hook looks:


import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useDebouncedValue = <T>(value: T, delayMs: number) => {
  const [debouncedValue, setDebouncedValue] = useState<T>(value);

  useEffect(() => {
    const timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
      setDebouncedValue(value);
    }, delayMs);

    return () => {
      clearTimeout(timeoutId);
    };
  }, [debouncedValue, delayMs, value]);

  return debouncedValue;
};

export { useDebouncedValue };



In my search form component I use the useDebouncedValue hook for query input in the following fashion:


/* I omitted some lines of code for brewity */
const SearchForm = ({ customClassName }: SearchFormProps) => {
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  /* todo: maybe I should use new useDeferredValue react-hook here ? */
  const debouncedSearchQuery = useDebouncedValue(searchQuery, 250);   

  return (
    <form
      name={`searchForm`}
      autoComplete={'off'}
      className={cn(customClassName, searchform)}
      ref={ref}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
    >
      <input
        type='text'
        name={queryParameters.productSearchQuery}
        placeholder={'I am looking for...'}
        className={searchform__input}
        value={searchQuery}
        onChange={(e) => setSearchQuery(e.target.value)}        
      />
      <button type={`submit`} className={cn(button, searchform__button)}>
        <SearchIcon className={searchform__icon} />
      </button>
      <SearchResults
        query={debouncedSearchQuery}
        isFocused={isFocused}
        setIsFocused={setIsVisible}
      />
    </form>
  );
};

export { SearchForm };



Then in SearchResults component (which is wrapped in memo) I fetch a list of matched products in infinite scroll way from back end, so the list of products can be quite long. Fetched products may have variations in the corresponding array property (rest of properties are ommitted for brewity):


interface ProductDTO extends IEntityId {
  name: string;  
  variations: {
    ids: Id[];
    byId: {
        [key: string]: {
            name: string;
        }
    }   
  }; 
}



If product has variations I render all its variations that match search query by full name (name of product + variation's name):


Object.values(product.variations.byId)
    .filter((variation) => {
        const fullName = product.name + ' ' + variation.name;
        return fullName.toLowerCase().includes(query.toLowerCase());
    }).map(/*...render search result card*/)



So I guess in the context of long list of products such filtering job can take some time.
Benefit of using useDebouncedValue in this context:

app doesn't make many unnecessary requests during input.
as SearchResults component is wrapped by memo and debouncedValue doesn't change during input, our searchQuery state in SearchForm updates without any lag, so we kind of get a proper UX.

BUT! The con comes under the next circumstances: when user stops typing -> debounced value is assigned the latest searchQuery value -> SearchResults component starts to fetch new portion of products, filters them, renders and at this point of time user tries to type something and BOOM! user's input is lagging resulting in bad UX.
useDeferredValue seems to solve the BUT issue by interrupting the SearchResults component's render. But in case of using useDeferredValue we resort to making lots of unnecessary requests. By the way I use react-query library's useQuery hook, which allows me to easily cancel unfinished requests. So I incline to the decision of leveraging useDeferredValue + useQuery with unfinished requests cancel.
What do you think would be the best option for my case?

Yes, you generally want to useTransition or useDeferredValue. However, some of those requests might still hit your server if cancelled. They can be cancelled when they already established contact with the server. Really, you want to useTransition around the part that actually sets the results back from the server. But seperately wrap the thing which makes the network call in a debounced callback https://www.npmjs.com/package/use-debounce#debounced-callbacks. That way you control how much it hits the server, as well as solve the problem of laggy ui when it does render.

To clarify both of these changes would really need to happen inside SearchResults. The problem with doing this in SearchForm is you can only control query. And query drives both the network request and the setting of the results. You need different strategies for those things, and so you cant do that at this level because you cant control them individually. Inside of SearchResults or whatever does the network call/set results, you can disambiguate them. Your mental-model atm is conflating these two things. They can be controlled individually. And probably should here.

@adsy, As I mentioned I use useQuery hook from react-query library as it provides me with built in solution for requests caching. And the only way I can imagine exploiting useTransition here for setting results from server is to create a dataCopy state variable with useState hook, and then setDataCopy inside startTransition callback in useEffect's callback on useQuery's isSuccess variable equals true, and eventually filter and render products and their variations based on dataCopy variable, which is set with the help of non-blocking useTransition

@adsy, Sorry, but I can't understand what would be the problem with using debounced variable from my useDebouncedValue hook inside SearchForm and then pass it to SearchResults, the debounced value is something that triggers useQuery to make a request => in this case no different debounced value = no new get request. Exploiting the debounced variable from SearchForm and setting data from server to dataCopy stateVariable with useTransition and then filter & render based on dataCopy does solve the issue of junky input and making multiple unnecessary requests. Cool!

I guess you could instead useDeferredValue on the results of the query and the use the result of that to render the search results. All of this is skipping around something though that I cant beleive I forgot to mention the first time. If the rerender with lots of results is expensive, you really ought to make that cheaper. If  its a lot of items, you need virtualisation. Which would make a huge difference. See https://tanstack.com/virtual/latest. This way, even if the list is large, the rendering will be much cheaper.

Yeh the idea of having a copy and useTransition over updating it in an effect is pretty much the same as useDeferredValue on the data and using that (I think). Those two hooks are two ways of doing the same thing.

Its not a problem actually that you are using debounced variable and passing it to search results. I was unclear. To be more specific -- changes are needed below where the useQuery is to be able to control the results setting and that part cant be done in the form component. Sounds like youve figured that though :). The debounce being up there is probably fine tbh.

@adsy, lol, yeah you are right I went by a path of reinventing bicycle.

But also I'd definitely look into virtualisation! This will also yield big gains and improve page performance in general not just the render but afterwards as you scroll etc if theres tons and tons of results.

@adsy, I think you can leave useDeferredValue for useQuery data solution as an answer here, thanks (:
